# Jquery counter plugin Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to implement JQuery Counter Plugin but I'm getting an error:

> dashboard:694 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).counterUp is not a function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"integrity="sha384q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.counterup.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="task-stat"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Total tasks today<br><h2><span class="counter" data-counterup-time="1500" data-counterup-delay="30" data-counterup-beginat="100">{{$tasks->count()}}</span></h2></div>
<script>
$('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000,
    offset: 70,
    beginAt: 100,
    formatter: function (n) {
      return n.replace(/,/g, '.');
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perhaps wrong path `<script src="jquery.counterup.min.js"></script> `, maybe it should looks like `<script src="assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>`. It depends on your project directory tree

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Counter-Up/1.0.0/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="task-stat"><i class="icon-tasks"></i>Total tasks today<br><h2><span class="counter">1000</span></h2></div>
<script>
$('.counter').counterUp({
    delay: 10,
    time: 1000,
    offset: 70,
    beginAt: 100,
    formatter: function (n) {
      return n.replace(/,/g, '.');
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @jayakumar its working , can you please explain what you changed ?

Comment: I removed {{$tasks->count()}} to limit value and updated to cdn URL

Comment: @PrabhatKumar Yes but JQuery version seems not an issue but <span class="counter">1000</span> only updated. Whatever values inside mentioned css class its input

Comment: Ohk..I have verified  it Either we have to udpate the jquery version from 
 `jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"` to 
`jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js` OR we have to udpate the waypoints js from `waypoints/2.0.3/waypoints.min.js` to `waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.min.js`

Answer (score 0):

Update your waypoints.min.js library version

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two calling of jquery.waypoints.min.js or jquery.counterup.min.js comment one of them in other's file's.